# Redirect loop in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-4

How to use before filter in Laravel in a group?

```
Route::group(['before'=>'auth','domain' => 'm.domain.us'], function(){
    ...
    Route::get('/','PageController@index');
});
```

I tried in this way, if I use only domain in group it works but I want to use auth filter
on all pages in this group because it is admin section and when I entered `'before' => 'admin'` and it gets an error:

> This webpage has a redirect loop.

Where is the problem here?

Comment: How about your auth filter? I feel your auth filter redirect to admin section and check the login status and redirect again.

Comment: if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('login');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this occurs because your Login-Route is inside your `::group-filter`.
This means: Program checks also on login page if user is logged in. Of course, the user is not -> `Redirect::to('login')` ... There you have your loop =)