# laravel login infinite loop after deployment

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-forge

I'm using Sentinel - https://github.com/rydurham/Sentinel - to handle user auth for my app, and have the entire 'admin' subdomain in routes.php wrapped up like so:

```
Route::group([ "domain" => 'app.domain.dev', 'before' => 'Sentinel\auth' ], function()
{
    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'one'), function()
    {
        ...
    });

    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'two'), function()
    {
        ...
    });

    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@index'));
});
```

On a local machine, everything works fine - app.domain.dev displays the admin dashboard if logged in, and the login page if not, while logging out returns the user to the login page.

Once deployed via Forge, however, app.domain.dev causes an infinite loop error if not logged in. Yet /login is still accessible and working - once logged in, the dashboard loads fine. If the user logs out, they hit the infinite loop error again.

I'm not sure why this works locally and not deployed, but I'm guessing it's something do to with the 'home' route sitting inside the 'Sentinel\auth' filtered group?

Sentinel's auth filter:

```
Route::filter('Sentinel\auth', function()
{
    if (!Sentry::check()) return Redirect::guest(Config::get('Sentinel::config.routes.login'));
});
```

...and config.routes.login is set to 'login'.

I understand the similarities of this question - [Redirect loop in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23147712/redirect-loop-in-laravel) - but it's the working locally / broken deployed that confuses me.

Comment: Hi do you have different environment defined in your app ? Because if you experience those kind of differences between your local setup and production setup, that may be the cause.

Comment: I do, yes - local and production, respectively - but I can't see where that would interfere with either the routes or Sentinel/auth.

I've also tried renaming the production environment to local on the deployed server (copying over the necessary db details, etc) to no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of solved it. As the link suggested, the easiest (hackiest) way is to remove the root, erm, route from the auth group:

```
Route::group([ "domain" => 'app.domain.dev' ], function()
{
    Route::group([ 'before' => 'Sentinel\auth' ], function()
    {
        Route::group(array('prefix' => 'one'), function()
        {
            ...
        });

        Route::group(array('prefix' => 'two'), function()
        {
            ...
        });

        Route::get('dashboard', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@index'));
    });

    Route::get('/', function()
    {
        if(!Sentry::check()) return Redirect::to('login');
        elseif(Sentry::check()) return Redirect::to('dashboard');
    });
});
```

I'm sure there are more elegant solutions, but I leave this here in case it's of any use.